# Compilation Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gson, build.gradle

My project was compiling perfectly 2 days ago and to day I have been getting the errors below :

Error:(17, 23) error: package com.google.gson does not exist
Error:(324, 51) error: cannot find symbol class JsonElement

Please refer to image below :
[image: Reference]

I have tried Rebuilding the project,and also invalidate all caches but no luck.

Comment: You aren't compiling Gson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library seems to be missing.
Make sure you add the dependancy in your app build.gradle file as following:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Check that you added gson to dependencies{} in build.gradle of app looks like this:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade your buildToolsVersion to "23.0.1",like this:

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"